# Updates and Row Level Security - No Difference Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are using RLS (row level security) in SQL Server 2016, yet we're seeing no difference in effect with using `BEFORE` versus `AFTER` in our update block predicate. Using the below code as an example for the security policy, if I were to switch this to `AFTER UPDATE` the effect would be the exact same - a user could not update any rows except their own.

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY ExamplePolicy
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.tvfExample(UserColumn) ON dbo.ExampleTable
ADD BLOCK PREDICATE dbo.tvfExample(UserColumn) ON dbo.ExampleTable BEFORE UPDATE
```

The function simply returns values where the UserColumn matches the person running the query. So Jane Doe would only see rows where the UserColumn has JaneDoe in the row. If Jane Doe wanted to update rows, she could only update her rows and no one else's data. However, whether I specify `BEFORE UPDATE` or `AFTER UPDATE`, there's no difference in effect - Jane Doe can't update anyone else's data.

However, when I research the differences with these in Microsoft, this is quoted from their [learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16):

- After update: prevents users from updating rows to values that violate the predicate.
- Before update: prevents users from updating rows that currently violate the predicate.

In what example would we use one over the other, as in terms of preventing Jane Doe from updating rows of data that don't belong to her, she can't do this with either of these?

Comment: With `BEFORE UPDATE` they could take their own rows and update them to become someone else's.